# Specifying Default Template for Hierarchal Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, hierarchical, customization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [single-{$post_type}-{slug}.php for custom post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40994/single-post-type-slug-php-for-custom-post-types)

I have [registered a Custom Post Type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) named `conference` with the attribute:

```
'hierarchical' => true
```

In the backend admin, I created this nested post hierarchy for my `conference` posts:

```
Conference: Finding Vision (slug: 2011-finding-vision)
  -  Schedule (slug: 2011-finding-vision/schedule)
  -  Speakers (slug: 2011-finding-vision/speakers)
Conference: Returning to Basics (slug: 2012-returning-to-basics)
  -  Schedule (slug: 2012-returning-to-basics/schedule)
  -  Speakers (slug: 2012-returning-to-basics/speakers)
etc...
```

I know I can use `single-conference.php` as a default template for any of my `conference` post types.  This works well for the parent conference posts.

*My Question*:  Is there a default template that I can use to target posts that are child posts of a `conference` post?

Is there a way to have WordPress load `single-conference-speakers.php` or `conference-speakers.php` by default when rendering the url `2012-returning-to-basics/speakers`?

With pages, this works.  If I have a page with a slug of `about`, then I know I can make a template with `page-about.php` to have the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) use that template as a default template.

Does the equivalent exist for custom post types?

Comment: I would recommend re-thinking your schema. "Conference", "Schedule", and "Speaker", while *related*, are not the *same type of content*. You might be better-served by using a combination of *Custom Post Types* and *Custom Taxonomies*.

Comment: That makes sense and does get at an underlying issue in my design.  However, I'm still curious about whether there is an answer to my question.  For instance, if instead of "conferences" this was "groups" how would I have sub-group templates?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't. You'd have to do as @m0r7if3r suggests, and do some conditional querying within `single-$posttype.php`.

Comment: @kaiser the other post pretty much answers my question in far better detail.  I'm fine with closing this.

Comment: In the future, please don't delete a dupe post like this (others had already linked to it). Moderators can merge duplicate posts so that useful answers aren't lost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it does exist, but it should. Try it and see. If it does not, you can use `if` statements within the `single-$posttype.php` in conjunction with `is_page()` (and the other conditional tags(http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), if needed) to duplicate that functionality.