# Change page template programmatically ?

Tags: pages, templates, language

I have two page templates and Qtranslate installed.

I want to choose one or another depending the language selected.

Can I do something like this ?

```
if($q_config['lang'] == 'en'){
// load page-template_en.php
}else{
// load page-template_de.php
}
```

Any idea ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using the `template_redirect` hook.

Looks something like this :

```
 function language_redirect()
 {
      global $q_config;

      if( $q_config['lang'] == 'en' )
      {
           include( get_template_directory() . '/page-template_en.php' );
           exit;
      }
      else
      {
           include( get_template_directory() . '/page-template_de.php' );
           exit;
      }
 }
 add_action( 'template_redirect', 'language_redirect' );
```

Code is untested, but should look like that.

See my similar answer [HERE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40994/single-post-type-slug-php-for-custom-post-types/41004#41004) for more help.

Comment: Don’t use template_redirect to load an alternative template file http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2014/02/19/template_redirect-is-not-for-loading-templates/

Comment: The exit will cause any subsequent script not to run. Use template_include, not template_redirect.

Answer (score 11):

Finally found it!
If I understand your question right, the template is basically saved as metadata that needs to be updated.

```
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'your_custom_template' );
// or
update_metadata('post_type',  $post_id, '_wp_page_template', 'your_custom_template' );
```

[Source and further info](http://tommcfarlin.com/programmatically-set-a-wordpress-template/)

Comment: This would store a permanent change to the page in the database. But, he needs to change the page dynamically, based on the user's language.

Answer (score 11):

The best (canonical) way is use `template_include` filter hook: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include

Example code:

```
function language_redirect( $template ) {
    global $q_config;
    $new_template = locate_template( array( "page-{$q_config['lang']}.php" ) );
    if ( '' != $new_template ) {
        return $new_template ;
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'language_redirect' );
```

Answer (score 6):

Should be possible using the `template_include` hook. Code is untested:

```
 add_action( 'template_include', 'language_redirect' );

 function language_redirect( $template ) {
      global $q_config;
      $lang = ( 'en' === $q_config['lang'] ) ? 'en' : 'de';

      $template = str_replace( '.php', '_'.$lang.'.php', $template );
      return $template;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for these suggestions !
I wanted to set "Elementor canvas" template by default on post only and I did like that :

```php
function default_post_template_elementor_canvas($post_type, $post) 
{
    $wishedTemplate = 'elementor_canvas'; // to see available template var_dump(get_page_templates($post))
    if ($post_type === 'post'
            && in_array($wishedTemplate, get_page_templates($post)) // Only if elementor_canvas is available
            && $post->ID != get_option('page_for_posts') // Not the page for listing posts
            && metadata_exists('post', $post->ID, '_wp_page_template') === false) {  // Only when meta _wp_page_template is not set
      add_post_meta($post->ID, '_wp_page_template', $wishedTemplate);
    }
}
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'default_post_template_elementor_canvas', 10, 2);
```